# Can I place a slide-in gas range up against plywood sheathing?

Tags: kitchens, code-compliance, range, sheathing

I'll be putting a slide-in gas range up against a knee wall.  However, I planned on bracing the knee wall with 3/4" plywood sheathing from the bottom plate up 30", where it would be completely covered by cabinets.  This sounded like a good idea until I thought about the range up against the plywood.  Can I do this? If not, what would be the appropriate way to put sheathing on the wall?

Plan B was to use 1/2" plywood and 3/8" drywall (or cement board?) over top of.  The existing wall covering is about 7/8" thick but varies a bit.  Looks to be 3/8" sheetrock from the 40's with a good 1/2" of plaster on top.

Comment: Does the range specify a certain air gap each side? Most do - check your installation instructions...

Comment: @SolarMike I would expect a slide-in gas (or electric) range to have **0** clearance needed in the back and ~ 1/4" on the sides - i.e., just enough to be able to slide it in place, but not any ventilation. Front and top are a different story. But the real question here is whether the back needs to be relatively fire resistant like drywall.

Comment: @manassehkatz the last gas stove I installed needed 5cm or 2” each side. I slid one out in a friend’s house once with about the 1/4” you mention to find two large black burn marks each side... but if you say 1/4” is sufficient then fine, I won’t be changing the 2” just yet.

Comment: In the end, it comes down to what the manufacturer recommends. Picking one at random [GE](https://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-30-in-5-0-cu-ft-Gas-Range-in-Stainless-Steel-JGBS66REKSS/206943135) [Specifications page](https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/db/db0e4cde-0625-44b2-a983-f5eb1b52e606.pdf) shows a big fat **0"** clearance both "To cabinets below cooktop and at the range back" - visually both sides and back.

Comment: My question isn't as specific to dimensions as it is, material.  I can look up clearance for my model, however, I haven't seen any mention of materials that it can be up against.  My thoughts are the back of the range my tend to get hotter than the sides, so there could be some requirements out there as far as materials, but I don't know where to look.

Comment: Kitchen cabinets that except built-in ovens are made out of plywood or particleboard.  If you’re concerned about it then cover it with a thin sheet of galvanized sheet metal or stainless steel for peace of mind.